# How to change hostname in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hostname

I've changed my domain from `RealPwned.de` to `RealPwned.eu` and when I type:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
```

it shows me wrong domain:

[image]

How can i change this to `RealPwned.eu`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't do it from MySQL, because this is a system variable set by MySQL service at start time, check out the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_hostname), as you can see it not persisted and can't be changed using `SET`, you can only change by modifying the server resolve name:

- **in linux** its in '/etc/resolv.conf'
- **in Mac OS** you can just change it through the following command: `sudo scutil --set HostName HOST_NAME`

After changing it you have to restart MySQL service, then it should be set to the new host name.

But this is too much to change for the system and you might not have access to the server. I suggest that you not depends on the `hostname` system variable in your DBMS, instead you have to make a configuration in your application or something that you have control over.

Answer (score 1):

The database server hostname resolves to the OS hostname.  In ubuntu hostname is changed by command:

```
sudo hostname [newhostname]
```

Other OS's will have their standard steps.